# HTML5 / jQuery: Working with custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I was wondering if someone could give me a hand with how exactly **data-*** works... I need to create a custom attribute which will be accessed with jquery...

heres what i got so far:

HTML

```
<select name='province' class='province' data-IsSelectSingle='true'> ... etc ...
```

jQuery

```
if($.data("IsSelectSingle") != "true")
```

and even though its true it executes still... ive also tried...

```
if($.data($(".province"), "IsSelectSingle") != "true")
```

Figured I'd try that since thats what it shows as the method on the jquery site but it doesn't seem to work either... any ideas why this might be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to grab the element via its selector (`.province`), and then use `.attr` or `.data` to get the data:

```
$(".province").attr("data-IsSelectSingle") != "true"
```

or

```
$(".province").data("IsSelectSingle") != "true"
```

Note, there are major differences between `.attr` and `.data`, and they way they handle HTML5 data attributes. See the docs for reference ([.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) & [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)).

Comment: hmm it seems to have worked using **$(".province").attr("data-IsSelectSingle") != "true"** but not with .data I'm gonna read up on .data a bit more none the less but your first solution definately worked thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Absolutely. :) Happy to help. And see that documentation... that use of `.data` should work for the data attribute. If it's not, there might be something else at play.

Comment: Actually, in more recent experience, I discovered what I believe has always been true about the .data method: it kind of "evals" the value of the attribute. So, for the above to work, @Lord-Link, you'd have to `!= true` (or better yet, `!== true`), instead of quoting `"true"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a selector for the data for it to know where to look for the data attribute.

```
if($("select.province").data("IsSelectSingle")!="true")
```